# Reverse a Pos Order Odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10, odoo

I created a pos sale, made payment, posted the journal entries and closed the session. Now i need to perform a reverse entry for that pos order. No need to make reverse the product. Because that sale should be considered as Free of Charge.

In new session,

1. Create a order with negative quantity & amount.
2. Make payment
3. Post the journals and close.

Are the above steps will be enough?

or

I need to create manual journal entry & post ?

Which solution is best?

Is there any other solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your attempted code, current output and desire out.

Comment: I am seeking any possibility to create a reverse entry against a pos order which is already paid and posted. I do not need to cancel or delete older one. Because we need to consider that order is free of cost.